# Excel formula for removing Zeros from a column and comparing with other

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula

I am trying to apply an Excel formula to sort the excel columns but not able to come up with it.

The excel entries looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, In the first column the records are having 000 at the end.

1) I need to neglect the last 000 from column A, compare the content of Column A with Column B.

```
   a) If it matches, then remove the 000 from the Column A.

   b) If it does not matches, then delete the entire row OR make the content for both the column as N/A.
```

Please help me out with this, the Content of this excel is a huge one, hence doing it manually is not feasible:(

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do this with VBA, you can add the following macro to your workbook:

**EDIT**

Your comment states that you're looking for both leading AND trailing zeros, not just trailing like the original question suggests. If that's the case, you can accomplish this by a simple conditional statement that checks where the 3 zeros are, if anywhere.

If possible, it would be much simpler to `Format` the cells `Number type` to remove leading zero's. If that's not possible, then here's the macro that achieves just that:

```
Public Sub CompareValues()
    Dim rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim firstCellValue As String
    Dim secondValValue As String
    rowCount = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim test As String
    For currentRow = rowCount To 1 Step -1

        'remove three leading or trailing 0's from value
        test = Left(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value, 3)
        If Left(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value, 3) = "000" Then
            firstCellValue = Right(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value, Len(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value) - 3)
        Else
            firstCellValue = Left(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value, Len(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value) - 3)
        End If

        secondValValue = Cells(currentRow, 2).Value

        If Not IsEmpty(firstCellValue) And Not firstCellValue = "" Then
            If firstCellValue = secondValValue Then
                Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = secondValValue
            Else
                Cells(currentRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Before Macro**

[image]

**After Macro**

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. Can you please let me know what if the three zeros are in front of each cell rather than present at the end? I am facing a scenario where in some cases the 0 is in front also :( This excel is a huge one, hence missed the front three zore scenario :(

Answer (score 1):

If the first column is always numeric and always has 3 zeros, then simply divide by 1000 and do the compare.

If not, then convert to a string and substr the first (length -3) characters and compare to the string result of the 2nd column